# Why is gigantism not called giantism?

Tags: medical

[Gigantism](http://www.healthline.com/health/gigantism) is a disease of having abnormally large size.

Is there a grammatical rule that says that it should be called "gigantism" and not "giantism"?

Comment: It's probably derived from gigantic rather than giant.

Comment: There are two words, giantism and gigantism. While they are synonymous (ie can be interchanged in some usages with little/no (no here) change in meaning, dictionary definitions of all senses are not identical.